React Admin routing issue
I have React Admin routing issue and now sure how to fix it.
<Resource
    name="licenses"
    icon={SchoolIcon}
    options={{ label: "Licenses" }}
    list={License}
>
      <Route path=":licenseId/calls" element={<Call />} />
      <Route path=":licenseId/calls/:id" element={<CallShow />} />
</Resource>

I have this license resource with list page created by react-admin. A data grid is created with a list of licenses.
I'm adding two new Routes to it which looks:

/:licenseId/calls - on licenses data grid row click - redirects and show list of calls by licenseId
/:licenseId/calls/:id - on calls by license id data grid row click - redirects and show details about selected call

This way I did the redirects from :licenseId/calls to :licenseId/calls/:id
 <Datagrid
   rowClick={(id: any) => `/licenses/${licenseId}/calls/${id}` }
 >

My issue is that once I click on the row from /:licenseId/calls (list of calls by licenseId list) there is an automatic api call to /licenses/:id but I'm expecting /licenses/:licenseId/calls/:id or no call to api

Which component does that API call? <Call>?
